# How to plot in 3D with a double entry table - Matplotlib

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I would like to plot in 3D with Pandas / MatplotLib (Wireframe or other, I do not care) but in a specific way..

I'm using RFID sensors and I'm trying to record the signal I receive at different distance + different angles. And I want to see the correlation between the rising of the distance and the angle.

So that's why I want to plot in 3D :

X Axis -> the Distance, Y Axis -> the Angle, Z Axis -> the signal received which means a float

My CSV file from where I generate my DataFrame is organized like this a double entry table :

```
Distance;0;23;45;90;120;180
0;-53.145;-53.08;-53.1;-53.035;-53.035;-53.035
5;-53.145;-53.145;-53.05;-53.145;-53.145;-53.145
15;-53.145;-53.145;-53.145;-53.145;-53.145;-53.145
25;-53.145;-52.145;-53.145;-53.002;-53.145;-53.145
40;-53.145;-53.002;-51.145;-53.145;-54.255;-53.145
60;-53.145;-53.145;-53.145;-53.145;-53.145;-53.145
80;-53.145;-53.145;-53.145;-53.145;-60;-53.145
100;-53.145;-52;-53.145;-54;-53.145;-53.145
120;-53.145;-53.145;-53.145;-53.145;-53.002;-53.145
140;-51.754;-53.145;-51.845;-53.145;-53.145;-53.145
160;-53.145;-53.145;-49;-53.145;-53.145;-53.145
180;-53.145;-53.145;-53.145;-53.145;-53.145;-53.002
200;-53.145;-53.145;-53.145;-53.145;-53.145;-53.145
```

On the first label row we've different angles : 0°, 23°, 45°, ...
And the index of the DataFrame is the distance : 0 cm, 15 cm...

And the matrix inside represents the signal, so, values of Z Axis...

But I do not know how to generate a 3D Scatter, WireFrame... because in every tutorial I see people that use specific columns as axis.

Indeed, in my CSV file on the first row I've the label of all columns

```
Distance;0  ;23 ;45 ;90 ;120;180
```

And I do not know how to generate a 3D plot with a double entry table.

Do you know how to do it ? Or, to generate my CSV file in a better way to see the same result at the end !

I would be grateful if you would help me about this !

Thank you !

Comment: Hm, your z-values are always `-45`. Do you have more data or different subset which you can share?

Comment: These data are just informative. Indeed, the data should be between -20 and -70

Answer (score 1):

maybe `contour` is enough

```
b = np.array([0,5,15,25,40,60,80,100,120,140,160,180,200])
a = np.array([0,23,45,90,120,180])
x, y = np.meshgrid(a, b)
z = np.random.randint(-50,-40, (x.shape))

scm = plt.contourf(x, y, z, cmap='inferno')
plt.colorbar(scm)
plt.xticks(a)
plt.yticks(b)
plt.xlabel('Distance')
plt.ylabel('Angle')
plt.show()
```

displays

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can get a contour plot with something like this (but for the data shown it is not very interesting since all the values are constant at -45):

```
df = pd.read_csv(sep=';')
df = df.set_index('Distance')
x = df.index
y = df.columns.astype(int)
z = df.values
X,Y = np.meshgrid(x,y)
Z = z.T
plt.contourf(X,Y,Z,cmap='jet')
plt.colorbar()
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to stackoverflow, your question can be split into several steps:

### Step 1 - read the data

I have stored your data in a file called `data.txt`.

I don't know Pandas very well but this can also be handled with the nice simple function of Numpy called [`loadtxt`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/generated/numpy.loadtxt.html). Your data is a bit problematic because of the text 'Distance' value in the first column and first row. But don't panic we load the file as a matrix of strings:

```
raw_data = np.loadtxt('data.txt', delimiter=';', dtype=np.string_)
```

### Step 2 - transform the raw data

To extract the wanted data from the raw data we can do the following:

```
angle    = raw_data[0 , 1:].astype(float)
distance = raw_data[1:, 0 ].astype(float)
data     = raw_data[1:, 1:].astype(float)
```

With [indexing](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/arrays.indexing.html) the raw data we select the data that we want and with [`astype`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.astype.html) we change the string values to numbers.

### Intermediate step - making the data a bit fancier

Your data was a bit boring, only the value -45, i took the liberty to make it a bit fancier:

```
data = (50 + angle[np.newaxis,:]) / (10 + np.sqrt(distance[:,np.newaxis]))
```

### Step 4 - make a wireframe plot

The example at [matplotlib.org](https://matplotlib.org/gallery/mplot3d/wire3d.html#sphx-glr-gallery-mplot3d-wire3d-py) looks easy enough:

```
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
ax.plot_wireframe(X, Y, Z)
plt.show()
```

But the trick is to get the `X, Y, Z` parameters right...

### Step 3 - make the `X` and `Y` data

The `Z` data is simply our `data` values:

```
Z = data
```

The `X` and `Y` should also be 2D array's such that `plot_wireframe` can find the x and y for each value of `Z` in the 2D arrays `X` an `Y` at the same array locations. There is a Numpy function to create these 2D array's:

```
X, Y = np.meshgrid(angle, distance)
```

### Step 5 - fancing it up a bit

```
ax.set_xticks(angle)
ax.set_yticks(distance[::2])
ax.set_xlabel('angle')
ax.set_ylabel('distance')
```

### Putting it together

All steps together in the right order:

```
# necessary includes...
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import axes3d
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

raw_data = np.loadtxt('data.txt', delimiter=';', dtype=np.string_)

angle    = raw_data[0 , 1:].astype(float)
distance = raw_data[1:, 0 ].astype(float)
data     = raw_data[1:, 1:].astype(float)


# make the example data a bit more interesting...
data = (50 + angle[np.newaxis,:]) / (10 + np.sqrt(distance[:,np.newaxis])) 

# setting up the plot
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')

# the trickey part creating the data that plot_wireframe wants
Z = data
X, Y = np.meshgrid(angle, distance)

ax.plot_wireframe(X, Y, Z)

# fancing it up a bit
ax.set_xticks(angle)
ax.set_yticks(distance[::2])
ax.set_xlabel('angle')
ax.set_ylabel('distance')

# and showing the plot ...
plt.show()
```

Comment: Niceeee that works perfectly ! I mean check this out (with specific values in data) https://imgur.com/a/7H5IFkT... But do you know how to plot in a 'popup' window. I mean, it would be better if I could you know, move the camera the show from an another view the Wireframe ! (thanks btw !)

Comment: I've my perfect data now and I don't know how to reach them with this row data = (50 + angle[np.newaxis,:]) / (10 + np.sqrt(distance[:,np.newaxis])). I would like to take my data in the array instead